# Method error when called on a variable created by another method

Tags: java

When I call my getUserInput and enter a 2d Char array that I made using my createBoard method it prints "That input was invalid! Please enter another.". I then enter another/or same value and I get an IllegalArgumentException.

However if I use the exact same code and call it on a 2d array that I made and initialized in the method, like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char a = ' ';
    char b = 'x';
    char c = 'o';

    char[][] n = {{a,a,a},
                  {a,b,b},
                  {a,a,a}};

    displayBoard(n);
    getUserMove(n);
    displayBoard(n);
}
```

The code works perfectly. Please help I can't find my issue :/ 
I've included the createBoard and getUserMove methods below. Thanks!

```
public static char[][] createBoard(int n) {     
    char[][] charArray = new char[n][n];

    for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        for (int v = 0; v < i; v++) {
            charArray[i][v] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return charArray;
}

public static void getUserMove(char[][] n) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    int row = in.nextInt();
    int col = in.nextInt();

    do {
        if (row < n.length && col < n[0].length && n[row][col] == 32) {
            writeOnBoard(n, 'x', row, col);
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("That input was invalid! Please enter another.");
            if (! in2.hasNextInt()) {
                in2.next();
            }
            row = in2.nextInt();
            col = in2.nextInt();

            writeOnBoard(n, 'x', row, col);
        }

    }while(row > n.length - 1 || col > n[0].length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Why is your inner loop only going up to `i` instead of to the length of the inner array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This for loop is broken:

```
for(int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    for (int v = 0; v < i; v++) {
        charArray[i][v] = ' ';
    }
}
```

First iteration, lets look at the code from the top. In your first `for` loop you initialize `i` as 0, but then in second `for` loop you initialize `v` as 0 as well and check if `v < i`. This is not right.